# События мыши. PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, qgraphicsview, mousepressevent

Не понимаю, как заставить отлавливать движения и нажатия мыши на определенных виджетах моего приложения.
В книжках пишут, "следует наследовать класс, реализующий графический объект, и переопределить в нем методы...". 
У меня сразу вопросы, кому наследовать, как... непонятно.

Например:

У меня есть класс с описанием Qt-виджетов. В виджете `QGraphicsView` отображаю картинку, на которой хочу отлавливать движение мышки. К этому `QGraphicsView`, должна быть подключена сцена (`QGraphicsScene`), к которой в свою очередь должен быть подключен графический объект(`QGraphicsPixmapItem`), к которому применен метод `setAcceptHoverEvents(True)`. 
А далее переопредяляю функцию `mouseMoveEvent`.

Но всё это у меня не срабатывает.
В чем ошибка, или в чем заключается основной принцип работы с графическими сценами?

Answer (score 1):

Для объекта не отловишь, событие mouseMoveEvent сработает только тогда, когда мышью нажмешь на объект, и с нажатой кнопкой повозишь мышь по этому объекту, еще на всяк случай флаг установить.
self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsFocusable, True)

Answer (score 1):

Можно переопределить событие движение мыши для сцены. А потом в методе сравнивать текущую позицию объекта и положение мыши, и вызывать свою функцию

```
   class Scene(QGraphicsScene):
   def __init__(self,rect):
       super().__init__(rect)
   def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
       print(e.pos())
```

Answer (score 0):

> Как отлавливать нажатия мыши на определенных виджетах приложения? 
>   В книжках пишут, "следует наследовать класс, реализующий графический объект, 
>   и переопределить в нем методы...". 
>   У меня сразу вопросы, кому наследовать, как... непонятно.

Следует наследовать класс, реализующий графический объект и переопределить в нем метод `mousePressEvent`,
например:

```
# создаем класс `CustomView`, который наследуется от `QGraphicsView`
class CustomView(QGraphicsView):            
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomView, self).__init__()
        ...

    # переопределить в нем метод `mousePressEvent`
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        ...
        super().mousePressEvent(event)
```

---

Если вы хотите оперировать с примитивом QGraphicsPixmapItem,
например, выбирать его и перемещать, 
вам нужно установить соответствующие флаги так:

```
self.setFlags(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable | QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
```

---

**Важно !**

1. Порядок доставки событий:  **Вид -> Сцена -> Элемент**.
2. Следует обратить внимание на одну вещь: если мы повторно реализуем функцию события,
   мы должны вызвать соответствующую функцию события родительского класса, 
   иначе событие не может быть доставлено гладко. 
   Если удалить строку **`super().mousePressEvent(event)`** под функцией события в классе `CustomView`, 
   консоль будет выводить только `событие из QGraphicsView`:
3. Графическое представление основано на декартовой системе координат, 
   **у представлений, сцен и примитивов есть свои *собственные координаты*** !

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView, \
        QGraphicsRectItem, QGraphicsPixmapItem, QGraphicsItem
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QTransform, QBrush, QColor, QPen


class CustomItem(QGraphicsPixmapItem):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomItem, self).__init__()

        self.setPixmap(QPixmap('ball.png').scaled(70, 70))
        # ...                 позволяет выбирать его и перемещать
        self.setFlags(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable | QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
        # установить смещение изображения от начала координат сцены
        self.setOffset(115, 115)  

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print(f'x = {event.pos().x():>4.0f}, y = {event.pos().y():>4.0f} <- QGraphicsItem') 
        super().mousePressEvent(event)


class CustomScene(QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomScene, self).__init__()
        # вызовите метод setSceneRect (x, y, w, h),
        # чтобы установить начало координат координат и размер сцены.
        self.setSceneRect(0, 0, 300, 300)
        self.addRect(self.sceneRect(), pen=QPen(QColor(230, 30, 230), 3))      

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print(f'x = {event.pos().x():>4.0f}, y = {event.pos().y():>4.0f} <- QGraphicsScene') 
        super().mousePressEvent(event)


class CustomView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomView, self).__init__()
        self.resize(400, 400)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print(f'\nx = {event.pos().x():>4.0f}, y = {event.pos().y():>4.0f} <- QGraphicsView') 
        # Возвращает точку координат области просмотра, сопоставленную с координатами сцены.
        print(f"x = {self.mapToScene(event.pos()).x():>4.0f}, "
              f"y = {self.mapToScene(event.pos()).y():>4.0f} <- mapToScene <- QGraphicsView")
        super().mousePressEvent(event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view  = CustomView()
    scene = CustomScene()
    item  = CustomItem()
    scene.addItem(item)
    view.setScene(scene)
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]